# Any recommendations for Forecasting tool which can integrate with salesforce

Tags: forecast

Does anyone have any recommendations for Forecasting tool which can integrate with salesforce (or salesforce appxchange app)?
Salesforce forecasting is not working well for us because it does not allow you to forecast on custom fields on opportunity with overrides.

wanted to also understand if someone went down Buy Vs Build path?

Answer (score 1):

The new forecasting does allow forecasting on custom fields. Overrides may be a problem, but I'm not sure. Perhaps contact Salesforce support first to see about talking to the product manager or look at the product roadmap.

Please be cautious before building something - in my experience, when a company says that the tool doesn't work well for them, their business process could actually be improved by switching to one that would work well with the tool. I don't know your actual process, but please consider the third option of adjusting to fit Salesforce Forecasting.

Comment: Hi David. Just out of curiousity: where did you find info about the new forecasting supporting custom fields? I am wondering if that could be useful for us as we're having a similar problem..

Comment: I presented on Forecasting at Dreamforce 13. I admit that I don't know exactly where in the documentation it is, but since the product manager and I talked a lot about using it, and I set it up in a Spring 14 prerelease org, I know it's there.

Comment: I had Collaborative Forecasting enabled on one of my Spring '14 sandboxes, but there's no option to forecast based on custom fields. Just Product Family and Opportunity Splits. We are very eager to use the standard SF forecasting but need 1 additional field on top of Product Family that is not Product-related but OpportunityLineitem-related (a picklist containing Acquisition/Retention/Churn). Is it an option that you forward my question to the Product Manager to confirm whether this is or is not possible?

Comment: Oh, that's an interesting use-case. Forecasting is defined as the Opportunity amount (plus adjustements) per owner/split user and per forecast category. If you want to do something on a line-item, that's not going to give you forecasting data, and I don't think any tool will do that. Perhaps move that picklist to Opp or to the Product (but preferably the Opp).

Comment: OK, thanks for your reply and confirmation that our setup is indeed not supported. Next step is to attempt to have our business process fit the application :-)

Comment: This feature is now available with collaborative foresacting, when you add your custom amount field(s) as an opportunity split type.